How to bound scalarized gradient difference norm in terms of smoothness in convex optimization?
We know if a convex function is $\mu$-smooth, the following inequality is true:
$\| \nabla g (u) - \nabla g(v) \| \leq \mu \|u-v\|$
I want to derive an bound for the following slightly different term where the gradients are multiplied by scalars i.e. $\|\alpha \nabla g (u) - \beta\nabla g(v) \|$ only in terms of $\mu$ and $\|u-v\|$. In my current efforts, by rearranging the terms, I got following bound but it has an extra $\| \nabla g \|$ term. How can I get rid of it?
$\|\alpha \nabla g (u) - \beta\nabla g(v) \| \leq \alpha \cdot \mu \|u-v\| + (\alpha - \beta) \|\nabla g(v)\|$, or equivalently
$\|\alpha \nabla g (u) - \beta\nabla g(v) \| \leq \beta \cdot \mu \|u-v\| + (\alpha - \beta) \|\nabla g(u)\|$

This is not possible. In fact, you can always insert $u = v$ and have
$$
\| \alpha \nabla g(u) - \beta \nabla g(v) \|
=
|\alpha - \beta| \|\nabla g(u) \|
$$
and it is not possible to bound this term only by $\mu$ and $\| u = v \| = 0$. Note that even in case $\mu = 0$ you can have $\nabla g(u) \ne 0$.

Thank you very much!
